# error: /NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples$ make CUDA-9.1_Samples$ make CUDA-9.2_Samples$ make CUDA-9.3_Samples$ make

Tags: makefile, cuda, sample

I've had CUDA Toolkit 9.0 correctly installed on Ubuntu 16.04 with the package manager-based method since both the two commands

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
nvcc -V
```

returne the right infomation. However, it fails to `make` correctly when I tried to compile the official example NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples.

```
io@msi:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples$ make
```

The main output is

```
/usr/bin/ld: can't find -lcudart
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:334: recipe for target 'simpleMPI' failed
make[1]: *** [simpleMPI] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/io/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/0_Simple/simpleMPI'
Makefile:52: recipe for target '0_Simple/simpleMPI/Makefile.ph_build' failed
make: *** [0_Simple/simpleMPI/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

can anyone give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: echo $PATH and echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH show both "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin" and "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64" have been set.

Comment: PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH do not effect compilation behaviour

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what is the "working MPI"? And I did't see it in the official installation guide. So how should I check if it has been installed in my system. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved this problem. As I mentioned in the question, I've had CUDA Toolkit correctly installed in my computer, but it fails when execute

```
io@msi:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples$ make
```

However, the following two commands

```
$ ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery
$ ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/1_Utilities/bandwidthTest/bandwidthTest
```

gives correct response "Result = pass". It's ok to ignore the "make error" listed above- I think.